# How to read multiple files and write into single .csv file c#

Tags: c#

My intention is opening 2 files (one .txt and one .csv), filter some text and finally write it into one column of single .csv file. Here is my code

```
OpenFileDialog fopen = new OpenFileDialog();
fopen.Multiselect = true;
fopen.Filter = "(All type)|*.*";
fopen.ShowDialog();
if (fopen.FileNames != null)
{
 //try
 //{
 Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
 //Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fopen.FileName);
 Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.Sheets[1];
 Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
 int row = 1;
 int col = 1;
 foreach (string file in fopen.FileNames)
 {

 textBox1.Text = fopen.FileName;

 string save = fopen.FileName;
 string save1 = save.Split('.')[0];

 string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(file);
 for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
 {
    textBox2.AppendText(text[i] + "\n");
    if (text[i].Contains("<LABEL-NAME>"))
     {
        if (text[i + 1].Contains("<MAP-LABEL-NAME>"))
         {
           string split = text[i].Split('<', '>')[2];
           string split1 = text[i + 1].Split('<', '>')[2];
           textBox3.AppendText(split + "\n");
           textBox3.AppendText(split1 + "\n");
           textBox4.Text = (split + ";" + split1);
           string split2 = textBox4.Text;
           range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, split2);
           row++;
           }
           }
            if (text[i].Contains("float32"))
              {

               string split = text[i].Split('f')[1];
               textBox3.AppendText(split + "\n");
               textBox4.Text = split;

               range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, split);
               row++;

                    }
                    textBox5.Text = row.ToString();
                }

                app.DisplayAlerts = false;
                wb.SaveAs(save1 + ".csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
                wb.Close();       //save as
                app.Workbooks.Close();
                app.Quit();
```

My problem is, the code has stop at

```
range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, split);
```

I try to pass the error but it has another problem is that just only the data filtered from the second file is written into the .csv file.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Why use excel to hold a bunch of strings to write out later?  Please make this a minimal viable code so we can run

Comment: The error come when I open 2 files at the same time, and it will stop at range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, split);. But when I  open just one, it's okay.

Comment: Looks like you have concurrency problems, Excel to write CSV is not the best choice IMHO, have you considered storing the info in memory and after the loop creating the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment isn't complete but you appear to be opening Excel outside your foreach loop but closing it before the end, hence it doesn't exist if you open more than one file.

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
.
.
foreach (string file in fopen.FileNames)
{
    //file stuff

//} foreach loop should be closed here.

            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            wb.SaveAs(save1 + ".csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
            wb.Close();       //save as
            app.Workbooks.Close();
            app.Quit();
//} missing foreach closing bracket but implied
```

The rest of the fragment is missing but you need to close the foreach loop before closing Excel.

Comment: Can you give it more specific? I'm new to c#. Thank you.